Would a question about patient-psychologist relationship be on-topic
I recently ended a series of sessions with a psychologist, and I did notice some issues that I found troublesome and that I could not address with her.
After some rest, I am considering the convenience of starting with another professional, but I would like to know if I can expect these things to repeat or if it just happens that I found some bad apple.
I do not know if that kind of question would be on-topic for this site, the help did not make it clear enough for me.

Welcome. Posts like these are off topic, because we do not answer questions relating to individuals. We can't provide medical advice either. We're a scientific stack, and basically here just for fun and for helping out with scientific problems. For medical care you should seek professional council.
I recommend to have a look at the site for asking questions in the Help Center. Completing the Tour may also give you much insight in the site's inner workings (and a badge :-).

Thank for your answer. To make myself clear, certainly I do not want medical care from here; as I explained I did already had one and I am considering hiring a new one. I will tell my personal issues to that professional, if I get one. But I would like to know what can I expect from that: for example would it be ok for my therapist to lie to me or to try to treat me for some issue we have not agreed about? Would that kind of more theoretical question on-topic?

@Mysterion - we don't answer opinion-based questions either. Take a look at the linked sites, please.

I did read the linked sites, thank you, and I am longtime user of stackexchange so I am used to them. But I do not understand why that question would be "opinion-based". Are not there ethical/thereapeutical guidelines addressing these kind of issues? That is what I want to know.

@Mysterion - in that case the Q should be posited much differently, like "Are there ethical guidelines for Psychologists that legally(?) enforces them to treat you only for a disorder that you really have and/or that a psychologist will treat you only for a disorder that we both mutually agreed upon' or something along those lines. Also mention the country and state you are in, as these matters may differ between country to country and state tot state

@Mysterion The main thing is that the question should not be specific to your situation.  General questions about psychotherapy ethics, procedure, legalities, etc, are on-topic here.
